identify movie where army goes back in time to ww1 or ww2 era
My father and I were talking about this movie, we saw it a VERY long time ago.
All I remember about it is, that the army(present day in the movies time) somehow either Bermuda Triangle or something, and they ended up in the WW1/2 era fighting old-school jet planes etc.
Any ideas? 

Have any other details like when you saw the movie, what year it could have been made as well as any recognizable stars?

How about The Final Countdown (1980)?
From the Wiki article:

In 1980, the supercarrier USS Nimitz takes on a civilian observer,
  Warren Lasky (Martin Sheen), at the orders of his reclusive and
  mysterious employer, Mr. Tideman (who helped design much of the ship),
  just before it departs Pearl Harbor for a training mission in the
  Pacific Ocean. Out in the Pacific, the ship encounters a strange
  storm-like vortex which disappears after the ship passes through it.
Initially unsure of what has happened and having lost radio contact
  with Pacific Fleet Command, as well as any of the U.S. fleet, the ship
  launches numerous aircraft to determine their status. After a
  reconnaissance aircraft discovers an intact pre-World War II Pacific
  battleship fleet at Pearl Harbor, an F-14 Tomcat patrol discovers a
  1940s era yacht, along with a patrol of Japanese Zeros.

